# Selenium WebDriver page interaction

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

Suppose a simple `http://mypage.com/` returns the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mypage.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Hello World!</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

So when I issue a Selenium `WebDriver.get("http://mypage.com")` command, the webdriver will attempt to load my page along with its `'mypage.js'`.

My question is: does the WebDriver go through the same "infrastructure" (i.e., the selenium-**webdriver** code) to also download `'mypage.js'` or is that already handled separately/innately just by the browser instance that comes up, completely independently of any WebDriver code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Selenium WebDriver controls the browser and does exactly what the browser would do if you were accessing that page. There will be no difference in loading the JavaScript using the WebDriver.

The [Selenium website](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) says:

> The biggest change in Selenium recently has been the inclusion of the WebDriver API. **Driving a browser natively as a user would** (...)

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the flow is something like this?: the "WebDriver" is not a browser, but rather a mechanism for controlling a browser that delegates all of it's commands to the *real* browser instance. Thus, in other words, the WebDriver simply tells a *real* browser instance to get `http://mypage.com`. When the real browser does so, the real browser (not the WebDriver controlling it!) will *also* get 'mypage.js' - and **not** through the WebDriver, but through *its own innate browser mechanism* -- the same way it would if it were NOT controlled by a WebDriver). Is this correct?

Comment: You are right. You probably never tested the WebDriver otherwise it would be clear to you. Try it locally and you will see your browser opened and being controlled automatically.

Comment: I know that the WebDriver can control the browser automatically, I just didn't know that the WebDriver is \*entirely dependent\* on the browser for practically *everything*. The WebDriver itself only knows how to *control the browser* --- it **cannot** do anything like downloading from the internet, parsing HTML, etc... "on it's own".